# How to read fabric environment variables set with cli

Tags: python, environment-variables, fabric

How can i read environment variables that I have set using the cli tool. For example, I have an empty fabfile.py in my cwd and when i run `fab --set password=foo,host_string=host1` and then run a python console to see if those fab environment variables were set -

```
from fabric.api import env
print env.host_string
```

I get nothing back ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#cmdoption--set), multiple `env` variables has to be comma-separated:

```
fab --set password=foo,host_string=host1
```

Demo:

```
$ cat fabfile.py
from fabric.api import env

print env['hello']
print env['world']
$ fab test --set hello=1,world=2
1
2
```

Comment: That was a mistake in my typing, printing host string returns None `print env['host_string']`

Comment: @Warz try `env.host_string` instead. Though it should work both ways.

Comment: Same issue, that was my original attempt. Am i supposed to be running python in a different location ?

Comment: @Warz that's interesting. I cannot reproduce the problem, see the `demo` section. What fabric version are you using?

Comment: I am using fabric 1.8.2. A couple things I noted in you're demo. I am not printing any environment variables in the `fabfile.py` because I plan on using fabric as a library without the fab cli. I just want to set environment variables with the cli tool once. Also, running `fab test --set hello=1,world=2` didn't work for me. I always get the error `Fabfile didn't contain any commands`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the host_string like that. That variable is set internally, after doing some string manipulation to the passed raw host. If you want to specify a specific host to use, call your fab task just use the flag for this and call your talk like:

```
$ fab -H host1 --set password=foo sometask
```

If you wanted to pass a host to a function you can also do this, but use a different variable name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I discovered that you can set and read the `host_string` and other various fabric environment variables but you can only read them within a fabfile `fabfile.py`. I ended up instead setting my fabric environment variables through OS environment variables